# Looking for a special graphics card

Tags: graphics-cards

For a special task of an application development, I'm looking for a graphics card with at-least two independently monitor-plugable HDMI outputs. It also must support at-least three monitors simultaneously. I'll use one of the HDMI ports to output some video-overlay graphics and with the other one, the associated alpha channel will be transmitted. The third display port will be used for displaying the UI to the user.

Currently the application is targeting the SDTV display mode (720x576@50Hz), thus the HDMI ports must support that mode, and the other denser HDTV display modes for the next versions! (however, the denser display modes are most probably supported!!)

Any recommendations for either *robust* and/or *regular* models is truly appreciated.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: So, to clarify: a graphics card with 2+ HDMI outputs, and 3+ total outputs? So, for example, 2xHDMI and 1xDVI is acceptable?

Comment: @ArtOfCode Hi, Yes of course, but the required display-mode and the HDMIs' independency also need to be considered :)

Comment: Last I checked the output of the HDMI is dependent on the OS on the settings you give it, not the card itself per se, correct?  So, a 3+ output GPU......Do you have any budget restrictions?  Also, what motherboard/chipset are you working with?  Your current power supply wattage would be good to know as well.

Comment: Hi @NZKshatriya :) thanks for the comment. Could you please elaborate on the _"HDMI output is dependent on the OS and the settings.."_, I don't know anything in that regard and I'm thrilled to know more about it. However, the display modes I'm after on the ports are a must, since the instruments receiving the output signal _only_ accept some very specific modes, while the HDMI ports may reside on _separate_ cards as long as I can output the signal in a correct display mode. The other parts (mobo, power, ..) will be determined based on the graphics card, assuming the budget is not an issue now!

Comment: I may be wrong on that, hence the ? at the end, but it also has to do with the resolutions acceptable to the target device.   Your SD device has an HDMI port?  I see a lot of cards with dual DVI, and several with 1x VGA, 1x DVI, 1x HDMI.   Technically you could use a DVI to HDMI adapter and thus have two HDMI connected devices, but as per the original question, I will look more until I have something that will qualify as an answer and not just comments.

Comment: @NZKshatriya Oh, I see :) Well, the target device doesn't have an HDMI port indeed, it's an SDI port and the output signal will be converted using an HDMI to SDI converter, so it's not like a monitor taking to the _"system"_ about the acceptance resolution and hence the display mode prerequestise! I don't know if the VGA is a better replacement for the HDMI for the display mode, I mean _do they support the SD res natively?_ in that case, I'll take a reconsideration! The DVI and the HDMI ports on most graphics cards I saw look to be mutually exclusive, you cannot plug two monitors simultaneousl

Comment: I have not seen an SDI port in a while, not since my dad brought stuff home when working for DEC (Digital Equipment Corporation) in the 90s.  From what I see in quick glance at convertors, they list input resolutions "up to" and then give the max resolution, and also output resolution "up to" with max resolution following....I know some of them do scaling and some don't.  but, its 1:39am here.  I'll do some more research...after a few hours rest.